# Как исправить проблему двойного ввода из за scanf? (Си)

Tags: c, scanf

Я новичок в си. Мне нужно проверить тип входных данных. Допустим только `float`, `str10` или `10str` быть не могут.

Программа работает, но только в конце всплывает двойной ввод. На скриншоте отмечено, что я имею ввиду. Заменить `scanf("%[\n]")==0` на `getchar` запрещено.

```
float str_ch()
{
    float n2;
    while (scanf("%f",&n2)==0)
    {
        printf("Введите число: ");
        scanf("%*[^\n]");
    }
    while (scanf("%[\n]")==0)
    {
        printf("Введите число: ");
        scanf("%*[^\n]");
        scanf("%f",&n2);
    }   
    return n2; 
}
```

[image: ![Текст](https://stackoverflow.com/SharedScreenshot1.png)]